# mongoDB test error

Tags: mongodb, database-connection

I came to know about mongoDB and looked for test.So I made it install and then for test when I used command mongo on terminal it showed an error like this

```
MongoDB shell version: 1.8.2
connecting to: test
Sun Jul 31 01:06:07 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:79
exception: connect failed
```

So can someone tell me what is the problem.I am using ubuntu 11.04.For installation instruction I had used [this](http://bradylove.com/2011/06/06/installing-mongodb-1-8-1-on-ubuntu-11-04) site.I am newbie to this mongoDB so please helpe me.Any help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like MongoDB isn't running. Can you connect to the [web interface](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface) in your browser?

http://localhost:28017

Also, do you see the process running on your machine? You should see an entry for **mongod** when running ...

```
$ top
```

or

```
$ ps aux
```

Answer (score 10):

All you need to do is open 2 terminal tabs. In one, run

```
mongod
```

which starts the MongoDB server.

In the other, run

```
mongo
```

which is the shell that connects to your MongoDB server.

Comment: I'm test-driving MongoDB for the first time and I didn't know I had to do this. Their documentation do explain you have to start `mongod`first and then run `mongo`, but if you're not Terminal literate, you won't understand you have to use two different tabs.

Answer (score 1):

why not install mongodb from 10gen's own debian repository? much easier and more likely to work

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages

To see if mongodb is running, this also helps:

```
sudo service mongodb status
```

if it is running, and you still get the same error, then it must be the weird localhost bug that mongodb has. it assumes localhost is 127.0.1.1 for some reason. try

```
mongo 127.0.1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Just try to create folder c:\data and next c:\data\db

Comment: in linux :
$ mkdir /data
$ mkdir /data/db